# How does NestJS match the injection target and the injected instance?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

According to the NestJS official document [[1]](https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#dependency-injection), it describes "In Nest, thanks to TypeScript capabilities, it's extremely easy to manage dependencies because they are resolved just **by type**."

I'm very confused of this description, because at runtime we do not have any type information of the constructor argument which is erased during the transpilation.

How NestJS actually resolves the matching between the required type (class) and the actual object (instance)?

Comment: they use reflect-metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to decorators, we actually have access to *some* types, through Typescript emitted metadata. It's with this metadata that Nest is able to read to know how to inject a class instance into a provider. This is the compiled JS from an `app.service.ts` to `app.service.js` file from `nest new`

```js
"use strict";
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.AppService = void 0;
const common_1 = require("@nestjs/common");
let AppService = class AppService {
    getHello() {
        return 'Hello World!';
    }
};
AppService = __decorate([
    (0, common_1.Injectable)()
], AppService);
exports.AppService = AppService;
//# sourceMappingURL=app.service.js.map
```

And this is the `app.controller.js`

```js
"use strict";
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
var __metadata = (this && this.__metadata) || function (k, v) {
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.metadata === "function") return Reflect.metadata(k, v);
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.AppController = void 0;
const common_1 = require("@nestjs/common");
const app_service_1 = require("./app.service");
let AppController = class AppController {
    constructor(appService) {
        this.appService = appService;
    }
    getHello() {
        return this.appService.getHello();
    }
};
__decorate([
    (0, common_1.Get)(),
    __metadata("design:type", Function),
    __metadata("design:paramtypes", []),
    __metadata("design:returntype", String)
], AppController.prototype, "getHello", null);
AppController = __decorate([
    (0, common_1.Controller)(),
    __metadata("design:paramtypes", [app_service_1.AppService])
], AppController);
exports.AppController = AppController;
//# sourceMappingURL=app.controller.js.map
```

If we look at the last few lines of `app.controller.js` we can see a line `__metadata("design:paramtypes", [app_service_1.AppService])`. This line means that the constructor of `AppController` has parameters of type `AppService` that should be passed to it. Nest is able to read this, check if there is an `AppService` in the module's container's providers, and if so pass the instance that is in the providers map to the `new AppController()`. This emitted type data is available for classes that have a decorator on them, and the emitted type value is always a class, whether it is the custom class used or if it is a primitive class like `Object` or `String`, though in the latter cases, there should be a custom parameter metadata being emitted via the `@Inject()` decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is nothing magical in there. Feel free to look https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/874344c60efddba0d8491f8bc6da0cd45f8ebdf7/packages/core/scanner.ts#L415

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but I'm still confused.
(i) Do you mean `DependenciesScanner.insertController` ?
(ii) The function only indicates `this.container.addController(controller, token);`. I do not think this does not answer my question "how does the container tell the required class without the class information erased during transpilcation?"

Comment: I can not find that thing, but probably @Decorators are generating the config object that is used in there.